# How to send cookies using Hasura

Tags: authentication, cookies, graphql, hasura, graphene-django

I am using Hasura to interface with a graphql endpoint on my django project using Graphene. I need to ensure that the user has authenticated for all calls to the graphql endpoint. In a typical rest api all you'd need to do is pass a session cookie back and forth and I would assume it's the same process with GraphQL.

I can interface with the graphql endpoint just fine using Postman, first authenticating with a rest endpoint then passing the cookies I received when making calls to the graphql endpoint.  When I copy the cookie to hasuras headers I am not receiving any cookies on the backend. This is effectively what I am setting the header to on hasura:

```
Set-Cookie : session=iLCJhbGciOiJIUzeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QI1NiJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiMzUzYWI5M2EtZmVmMi00ZjkyLTllYmItYjlmMDM3ODFkNzMwIiwiZXhwaXJlc19pbiI6IjIwMjAtMDUtMTJUMTk6MTM6MDkuOTc5MjA3WiIsImZpbmdlcnByaW50IjoiT3RoZXIgLyBPdGhlciAvIE90aGVyIiwiY3JlYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjAtMDUtMTJUMTg6NTg6MDkuOTg1NzQ0WiIsImlwIjoiMTI3LjAuMC4xIiwidXNlciI6IjYwNjYwMjgyLTI1ZGEtMTFlYS04YjAzLTRhN2I0YjZmMmYyYSJ9.WCm3GbbLXk-2kbhvKSUpNS-8ggHbEHrDi7YPuLtpvik; path=/; domain=localhost; HttpOnly; Expires=Wed, 13 May 2020 02:58:09 GMT;
```

I am trying to confirm I have cookies by inserting this code into a resolver but all that is printed is an empty dict.
`print(info.context.COOKIES)`

Comment: When running in the Browser cookies are handled by the Browser.  The Set Cookie header has to be the response from the Django authentication service, if both services are running in localhost, the Browser will automatically forward the cookies to Hasura.  If they are running in different domains, for security reasons the Browser will block it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Hasura in Heroku and running a Vuejs + Node.js application, I'm creating a cookie(HttpOnly, Secure) with a JWT as value, had setup the hasura HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET to:

```
{"type":"HS256", "key": "secret","header":{"type": "Cookie", "name": "namecookie" } }
```

Always returnig 'no cookie name in the header JWT', I'm sending a fetch from Vue direct to Hasura, I want to! even if it is unsafe. but it does not work.